# How are problems with the Unity Launcher debugged?

Tags: unity, launcher

I easily added an Intellij IDEA launcher icon, and locked it (IDEA creates the .desktop file).

Using the .local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop as an example it was easy to add another locked launcher for the Aventail Connect VPN.

All very simple, so I tried adding a launcher icon for Aqua Data Studio (ADS). This is a Java application launched by a bash script just like Intellij IDEA is.

If the ADS application is picked from Unity Dash it starts fine, and a Launcher icon appears.

**The problem is if this icon is pinned, and the icon is clicked on to start ADS, the icon flashes for a second or two, and nothing happens**. I turned "terminal" true hoping to see the reason for the failure to start, but the terminal does not even open. The other strange thing was when this icon was locked it immediately re-positioned itself to the top. This had not happened with IDEA or Aventail.

Is there a way to turn on logging to see exactly what the launcher
    is doing, and where the failure is?

By trial and error I found the following solution, but the system would not allow me to answer myself --

Do not provide a value for StartupWMClass by guessing. I had set:

StartupWMClass=datastudio

By leaving this key off the locked launcher works fine.

Comment: I am having the same issue that you'd and wanted a way to debug the action triggered from launcher. I wonder, if you ever figured that out?!